# MySQL - Storing Multiple Entries in 1 Field

Tags: mysql

Looking for some advice on how I might accomplish this MySQL task: I want to have a table with a list of orders (Table 1), but each order needs to have a list of a bunch of food items. So would I reference a different table in each row of Table 1 that holds these food items?

#### Table 1 -

```
customer: | reference to table | time placed | customer name|
```

etc.....

Comment: So, what is the actual question?

Comment: What the title asks for is called "denormalized" data, and is frowned upon in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what your schema should look like:

orders: id | table_id | time | customer_name

items: id | name

order_items: id | order_id | item_id

An order can have multiple food items and one food item can belong to multiple orders. Typical case of many-many mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct. You should make another table for order of food items in which you can place foreign key of customer and food item ordered and it's quantity. Then it will be 2nf normalized.
For more info about normalization

-[1nf](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/firstnormalform.htm)

-[2nf](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/2nf.htm)

Comment: actually one more question though, wouldn't this result in a new table for every new order?

Comment: You can put order no column in both tables. So for each order of customer there will be different items. You can also get bill of order from 2nd table directly.